# How can I generate a list of all repositories in my myrepos (mr) configuration?

Tags: configuration, scripting

For a scripting purpose, I want to print a list of all repositories in my myrepos (mr) configuration.

I have the following ~/.mrconfig:

```
[hell]
checkout = git clone 'git://github.com/chrisdone/hell.git' 'hell'
```

Assuming I have already cloned the repository in ~/code, when I run the following command at the working directory ~/code:

```
mr list
```

the command says

```
mr list: no repositories found to work on
```

What does `mr list` do? Is it not the command to print the all entries in the configuration like `vcsh list`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that the config section needs to be an absolute path in order to have `list` command process it.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran `mr ch` from your example user home it would clone into ~/hell and `mr ls` would then show results. If you want this to work off ~/code then you need the following.

```
~ $ cat ~/.mrconfig 
[code/hell]
checkout = git clone 'git://github.com/chrisdone/hell.git' 'hell'
~ $ mr list
mr list: failed to chdir to /home/user/code/hell/: No such file or directory

mr list: finished (1 failed)
~ $ mkdir code
~ $ mr ch
mr checkout: /home/steven/code/hell
Cloning into 'hell'...
remote: Counting objects: 265, done.
remote: Total 265 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 265
Receiving objects: 100% (265/265), 48.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (110/110), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

mr checkout: finished (1 ok)
~ $ mr list
mr list: /home/steven/code/hell

mr list: finished (1 ok)
```

Or place your original config in ~/code/.mrconfig and run commands under ~/code.